# Customize icon size Atom toolbar?

Tags: toolbar, atom-editor

I recently installed the atom editor and the packages `tool-bar`and `tool-bar-atom`. Unfortunately the icon size in the toolbar is quite large (please click the image to see the real size)

[image]

How can I customize the icon size? I am on a 4K display and assume that this is the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the icon size in the package settings (`Preferences > Packages`). Available sizes are 12px, 16px, 24px and 32px.

[image]